# On click of my menu button i want to open custom alert dialoge box but i was unable to do that

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

on click of menu i want to open alert dialouge box

actually error is comming view inflator ...
i don't know what to inflate in menu section
**inflate (int,menu) in menuinflator i don't know to what to inflate in under menu**

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {

            case R.id.add_to_playlist:

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_textview_inflator);
                builder.setView(view1);
                final EditText play_list_name = (EditText) view1.findViewById(R.id.alertTextEditor);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Editable m = play_list_name.getText();
                        String folder_name_act = m.toString();
//                                            addComment(folder_name_act);
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancil", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
                break;
            case R.id.delete:
                Log.e("qwerty", "delete");

                break;

        }

        return true;
    }
});


popup.show();

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_textview_inflator, null, false);
```

Comment: haven't you read my question. inflator is asking for only 2 parameter (int,menu)

Comment: Sorry brother, I have updated my answer. You have to use `Activity`'s inflater, not `menu`'s

Answer (score 0):

**I have slight changed your code. try this May Help you**

```
private void showPopUpMenu(View view){
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.add_to_playlist:
                    showAlert();
                    break;
                case R.id.delete:
                    Log.e("qwerty", "delete");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}

private void showAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_textview_inflator, null, false););
    builder.setView(view1);
    final EditText play_list_name = (EditText) view1.findViewById(R.id.alertTextEditor);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Editable m = play_list_name.getText();
            String folder_name_act = m.toString();
            //                                            addComment(folder_name_act);
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancil", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: i added this line and it worked                                                                   View view1 = View.inflate(getContext(),R.layout.alert_textview_inflator,null);